# Can i extend a category?

Tags: ios, objective-c, categories

I need to add functionality to an existing class.  That class has already been extended by a category and I need this extended functionality.  My question is, what's the cleanest and most proper way to add the new functionality?  Can I add another category to the class without affecting the one that already exists?  Can I subclass the category (is that even possible?)

My specific scenario is I have a `UIImageView+WebCache` for URL based images, but I want to add the ability for these to be clicked / tapped to take you to another URL which would be a property in the new category.  However, my question is more generally about categories in iOS and best practices.  IOW, how would one normally go about doing this?

Comment: @ryano How did you achieve this. I too have same requirement

Comment: @BeingLearner I created an additional category that I included in the same file where I was including the existing category and was able to use both categories on the same class simultaneously.  My needs were for additional functionality, I was not trying to override existing methods.  I basically implemented the accepted answer.  Watch out for method name collisions as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Thanks i will look at on accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I add another category to the class without affecting the one
>   that already exists?

You can have different categories on the same class and they wont intercept on each other. You just import the ones you need. If instead of that you want to extend an actual category, you can add the code to it.

Comment: One important note - be sure both categories don't add the same method. This results in undefined behavior.

Comment: Note that all categories *will* be loaded at runtime, regardless of the `#import` statements. The imports allow Xcode to give you proper autocomplete suggestions and to be explicit about which categories you intend to use, but the runtime will load all existing categories.

Answer (score 2):

You may safely create multiple categories for a single class. Some people prefer to create an "umbrella" category that contains all additional functionality, but it's usually advisable to create a new category for each purpose. This allows you to only import what you need to use in a particular context.